# Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool

Tags: python, macos, clang, otool

I am trying to execute brew commands on my system. But its keeps on throwing the same failure:

```
Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool

The configuration of the brew installed are : 

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
HEAD: ef01d1d92e8f57da8f75d3fb70c934f29ef875d8
Last commit: 2 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
OS X: 10.10.5-x86_64
Xcode: 7.1
CLT: 7.1.0.0.1.1444952191
clang: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or in PATH
Clang: N/A
X11: 2.7.7 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 2.0.0-p481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: N/A
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_65
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this on some website. That irrespective of the Python version you want to use to develop on `Mac OSX`. It should also has a Python 2.7 pre-configured with the system OS. I ended up deleting the older version from my frameworks and pointing to the latest version from `PATH` in `bash_profile`.

So in order to fix this you need to make sure your `Python Ver 2.7` is available in your `Frameworks`. `Do Not Delete It.`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar errors because I had neglected to accept the **Xcode** license agreement. Not sure if you're having the same issue.  You can run the below command to accept it, and then re-try the your `brew` commands:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```